# Как дать пользователю возможность ввода при выполнении цикла? (Python)

Tags: python

Когда изучал язык Python, решил сделать простенькую cmd-игру. Добавил "анимированный" текст, но пропала возможность вводить из-за цикла.
Я предполагаю что условие надо было вписать в сам цикл, но не знаю как правильно это сделать.

```
import os

flPress=True

Enter=['>>> Нажмите Enter <<<',
       ' >> Нажмите Enter << ',
       '> > Нажмите Enter < <',
       '>>  Нажмите Enter  <<']

while flPress:
    for i in Enter:
        os.system('cls')
        print(i)
        time.sleep(1)

if input()=='':
    print("Вы нажали Enter")
```

Comment: запустить 2 потока - в одном ожидаете ввода, во втором выполняете логику программы (к примеру)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Если хотите реализовать именно через `input()`, то можно вынести ожидание ввода в отдельный поток:

```py
from threading import Thread

...

def wait_input():
    global flPress

    if input() == '':
        print("Вы нажали Enter")
        flPress = not flPress

Thread(target=wait_input).start()

while flPress:
    ...
```

Но, как мне кажется, более верным решением будет подключить библиотеку для считывания клавиш:

```py
pip install keyboard
```

```py
from threading import Thread
import keyboard

flPress = True

def on_press_enter(e):
    global flPress
    print('Вы нажали Enter')
    flPress = not flPress

keyboard.on_press_key('Enter', callback=on_press_enter)
Thread(target=keyboard.wait).start()

...
```